# Adding incorrect value on calculated field pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a function that is supposed to add a new column with profit.

```
def profit(data):
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        #print row[0]
        profir_margin_L_A = 0.04
        profir_margin_E = 0.02
        if row[2]== 'Latin America':
#       row['profit'] = data.apply(lambda row: row[8]* profir_margin_L_A)
            data['profit'] = data['amount_eur_y'] * profir_margin_L_A

        else:
#             row['profit'] = data.apply(lambda row: row[8]* profir_margin_E)
            data['profit'] = data['amount_eur_y'] * profir_margin_E
    return data
```

And it return 0,02 percent for all rows, not only Europe.

I tried also this, but where only work for one condition.

```
test['profit'] = (test['amount_eur_y']*profir_margin_L_A).where(test['region'] == 'Latin America')
```

Calculated what i need, but when i cant combine condition for Europe.

In the end i need a data frame with correct profit calculated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` to create an array which is equal to `profir_margin_L_A` when `region == 'Latin America'` and `profir_margin_E` otherwise, and then multiply it with the `amount_eur_y` column:

```
test['profit'] = test['amount_eur_y'] * pd.np.where(test['region'] == 'Latin America', profir_margin_L_A, profir_margin_E)
```